# iterating through a json dict/object using python

Tags: python, json, sqlite

There is a json file that has data I am looking to throw into a database, but there are over 10000 entries. So I want to automate it.

Here is an example of the parsed json code through python:

```
{'product': {'product_data': [{'product_name': 'debian_linux',
                                                                                             'version': {'version_data': [{'version_value': '8.0'}]}}]},
                                                            'vendor_name': 'debian'}]}},
                    'data_format': 'MITRE',
                    'data_type': 'CVE',
                    'data_version': '4.0',
```

basically where it says `'product_name': 'debian_linux'` is what I'm after. I want to print out each product name in the json file, but only show 1 of the `product_name` if it has more than one entry (ex: there could be like 15 mentions of debian_linux, or windows_server_2008, but I only want to see one of those fifteen.)

I read the documentation for the `jsons` library, but it's hard to understand without having much experience with coding, but I gave it a shot and here is my code so far:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('nvd.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

pprint(data["product_name"])
```

I get an error saying `KeyError: 'product_name'`

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries; you need to know basic data structures.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know what data structures are.

Comment: Then why are you trying to access a key that clearly isn't in the dictionary you're trying to access it in?

Comment: I understand that these are nested dictionaries, or possibly also a list within a dict, but I am trying to figure out how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you have nested dictionaries, ie. you got to loop over them with e.g. `for key, values in data.items()` and then verify that the key corresponds to your `product_name`.

see also [iterating over dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out!

```
import json
import sqlite3

with open('nvd.json', 'r') as file:
    parsed = json.load(file)

for item in parsed['CVE_Items']:
    for x in item:
        for test in item['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data']:

            print(test['product']['product_data'][0]['product_name'])
```